# onResumeFragments() called after onSaveInstanceState()

Tags: android, android-fragments

My activity may show a `DialogFragment` when it resumes.  As suggested in this [fragment transactions tutorial](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html), I'm doing that in `onResumeFragments()` to avoid the dreaded `IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState`.  For the most part, all is well.

But my activity also has an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` that restarts the activity when a certain preference is changed.  The preference change that triggers the listener is caused by making a selection in a `Spinner`.  If the activity restarts itself by calling `recreate()`, I get the `IllegalStateException`.  But if the activity restarts itself like this, there's no problem:

```
finish();
final Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

I'd prefer to use `recreate()` because I want my instance state to be saved.  Why would this result in `onResumeFragments()` being called after `onSaveInstanceState()`?

Comment: What's your `IllegalStateException` message when restart by `recreate()`, is it `Can only be called on top-level activity`?

Comment: @sakiM "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"

Comment: Seems this message isn't thrown from `recreate()`, the direct exception from recreate is either `"Can only be called on top-level activity"` or `"Must be called from main thread"`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I feel kind of dumb.  I had a fragment that called `setRetainInstance(true)` but cached a reference to its activity in `onCreate(...)` instead of `onActivityCreated(...)`.  The fragment was attempting to display a dialog using the old activity.  (To be more precise, the activity was indirectly calling a method on the fragment from `onResumeFragments()`.)  Pretty messy.  I should probably rethink the whole relationship between the fragment and the activity.

**Edit:** I've since discovered another way this can happen that isn't my fault.  If the lock screen is shown over a running activity, `onSaveInstanceState()` is called.  But when the lock screen is dismissed, `onRestoreInstanceState()` is *not* called between `onResume()` and `onResumeFragments()`.  This bug is at least five years old.  Thanks, Google.